# Excel auto future date calculation

Tags: microsoft-excel

Hi am looking for advice on how to have excel display autopopulated calendar dates to keep track of patient visits that are set to occur at certain time intervals

For example, if I enter a date (today), it will populate the days on which the visit is set to occur in the future, and that if the original date that is used to calculate every subsequent date is not entered, the subsequent rows to the right will display 'N/A' or '-' ?

On Excel, I know I can do something like..

[image]

But when I remove the date in A1

I get these really strange numbers, is there a way to change this to display something else?

[image]

I've used something like this in the past, but did not get a chance to save that sheet. All I remember was that '$' was used.

I've tried googling this but cannot find what I am looking for. Could someone teach me how to program or write the formula to do this?

Thanks

Comment: What version of Excel do you have?

Comment: My version of excel is 2016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question this might work for you.

=IF(ISBLANK($A1),"N/A",A1+7)

[image]

[image]

Comment: BradR, Thank you so much!!! You are truly a lifesaver! A god of pure excel wizardry and genius!!! I seriously cannot thank you enough, I even played around and tweaked things for what I was trying to keep track of for my study patients. Thank you!!!